# What is the best way to convert a zope DateTime object into Python datetime object?

Tags: python, zope

I need to convert a zope 2 DateTime object into a Python datetime object. What is the best way to do that? Thanks, Erika

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
modernthingy = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(zopethingy.timeTime())
```

The `datetime` instance is timezone-naive; if you need to support timezones (as Zope2's `DateTime` does), I recommend third-party extension package [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 11):

Newer DateTime implementations (2.11 and up) have a `asdatetime` method that returns a python datetime.datetime instance:

```
modernthingy = zopethingy.asdatetime()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean [this](http://wiki.zope.org/zope2/DateTime) one

```
.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') =  04/25/2005 10:19
```

then reverse is

```
>>> time.strptime('04/25/2005 10:19','%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2005, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=10, tm_min=19, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=115, tm_isdst=-1)
```